# Generic Nullability In Expression

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I would like to know how should I change `KO` signature to allow generic nullability as `OK` does:

```cs
public class X {}

public static class G
{
    public static void OK<T>(T? p) where T: class {}
    public static void KO<T>(Expression<Func<X, T?>> p) where T: class {}
}

[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    string? value1 = null;
    string value2 = "hi";

    G.OK(value1);
    G.OK(value2);

    Expression<Func<X, string?>> expression1 = _ => null;
    Expression<Func<X, string>> expression2 = _ => "test";
    
    G.KO(expression1);
    G.KO(expression2); // Warning: (*1)
    // (*1) Argument of type 'Expression<Func<UnitTest1.X, string>>' cannot be used 
    // for parameter 'p' of type 'Expression<Func<UnitTest1.X, string?>>' in 
    // 'void G.KO<string>(Expression<Func<X, string?>> p)' due to differences 
    // in the nullability of reference types.
}
```

My goal is to avoid warning (*1)

#### What I have tried section:

I tried several approaches, for example, to create a new method `public static void KO<T>(Expression<Func<X, T>> p) where T: class {}` but error appears: `Type 'UnitTest1.G' already defines a member called 'KO' with the same parameter types`. Also, to create a different signature method `public static void KO<T>(Expression<Func<X, T>> p, bool ignore = false) where T: class {}` but warning remains (this approach works with `struct` but not with `class`.

This runs but is a bit dirty (I guess this is how I deal with nullables on EF model builder):

```
public class X {}

public static class G
{
    public static void OK<T>(T? p) where T: class {}
    public static void KO<T>(Expression<Func<X, T>> p) // <-- remove nullable
       where T: class {}
}

public void Test1()
{
    string? value1 = null;
    string value2 = "hi";

    G.OK(value1);
    G.OK(value2);

    Expression<Func<X, string>> expression1 = _ => null!; // <-- fake not null
    Expression<Func<X, string>> expression2 = _ => "";
    
    G.KO(expression1);
    G.KO(expression2); 
}
```

Comment: The warning is proper; there is no way for nullability analysis to know this scenario is "safe" -- and generic parameters cannot be attributed (yet), otherwise that would be a solution. I would instead suggest `Expression<Func<X, string?>> expression2 = _ => "test"`, which avoids the warning just as well; if you're willing to accept `null` it is of course fine if the expression always happens to be not `null`.

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert Are you so kind as to post it as an answer? I can accept it